# How can we access Facebook app insights through the v3.3 API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, analytics, facebook-apps

Is there a way to access Facebook application insights through the v3.3 API ? The Page / Post / App insights documentation mentions the following :

> App Insights are now returned by a separate /app/app_insights edge and
>   will no longer work with this edge in v2.1.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/insights

Although, the /app/app_insights edge is deprecated.

We are trying to access simple metrics from facebook application analytics as shown on the analytics dashboard on this URL:

https://www.facebook.com/analytics/{APP_ID}/

We need, if possible, the number of impressions/clicks for posts created by the application or any other metrics from our application.

Unfortunately, we found to way to access this data.

Comment: I don’t find any mention that this has be replaced by something else anywhere … maybe it’s just gone.

Comment: This is what I think. Facebook documentation is not the best.